# Do regular and secure connections always use different ports?

Tags: http, https, server, port

Can the server handle both regular TCP connections and TLS secure connections with a single port number? Or must I make each one separately?

I have always used each port.
And redirected http to https if needed.

I can't answer the above questions because of lack of foundation.
Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your question is.  However, if it is can the server handle http and https with one call, that would seem highly unlikely.  You are making a single call and that call must address a particular address and protocol.

You may be able to send that request with parameters that you could then on the server side send a request to the secondary protocol.  For example, if  you are sending a request via http; you could pass some parameters that server side code could utilize and then, make a secondary call to https.  However, this being said, why do you want to use multiple protocols?  I think it is best to first understand your actual need and use case before you proceed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this question is: can HTTP and HTTPS share the same port?

The answer is: No, they can't.

The reason is: HTTP and HTTPS are different application level protocol. Under the hood, HTTP and HTTPS requests are just a stream of bytes, and server needs the port information to know how to parse those bytes。

For example, if server find 1 request is coming from port 80, then it knows the bytes are in HTTP format, and parse those bytes to get reasonable data. If server find another request is coming from port 443, then it knows the bytes are in HTTPS format, and parse them using corresponding method. If server find a 3rd  request is coming from port 21, it knows the bytes is following FTP protocol and then parse...

If 2 application level protocol (such as HTTP and HTTPS) share the same port, it would be a disaster for the web server: for any request coming from that port, there is no way to know which protocol it is following, and server will not be able to parse the stream of bytes accurately.